# Blender keeps crashing when I try to render animation

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I have a scene I am trying to render, but Blender immediately crashes after clicking the render animation button. I have tried decreasing the resolution, switching from Cycles to Eevee, and lowering the max samples.

I am using Blender V. 3.6.5 on a Mac with OS 10.15.7 (Catalina)

Here is the scene:
https://blend-exchange.com/b/Mlr37bBg

```
Crash Report:
Process:               Blender [1431]
Path:                  /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender
Identifier:            org.blenderfoundation.blender
Version:               3.6.9 (3.6.9 2024-02-20)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Blender [1431]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2024-03-01 12:41:09.030 -0600
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.7 (19H2026)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        550C495C-3F29-1552-02D8-32BD0151E88E


Time Awake Since Boot: 7900 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   Blender [1431]

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x00000001049a4a5d IMB_gpu_clamp_half_float + 205
1   org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x00000001048c274f blender::draw::image_engine::ScreenSpaceDrawingMode<blender::draw::image_engine::OneTexture>::do_full_update_gpu_texture(blender::draw::image_engine::TextureInfo&, blender::draw::image_engine::IMAGE_InstanceData&, ImageUser const*) const + 351
2   org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x00000001048c156f blender::draw::image_engine::ScreenSpaceDrawingMode<blender::draw::image_engine::OneTexture>::update_textures(blender::draw::image_engine::IMAGE_InstanceData&, Image*, ImageUser*) const + 399
3   org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x00000001048c0e87 blender::draw::image_engine::ScreenSpaceDrawingMode<blender::draw::image_engine::OneTexture>::image_sync(blender::draw::image_engine::IMAGE_Data*, Image*, ImageUser*) const + 439
4   org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x00000001048c0801 blender::draw::image_engine::ImageEngine<blender::draw::image_engine::ScreenSpaceDrawingMode<blender::draw::image_engine::OneTexture> >::image_sync() + 497
5   org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x00000001048c01a9 blender::draw::image_engine::IMAGE_cache_init(void*) + 345
6   org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x000000010489e8eb drw_engines_cache_init + 155
7   org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x000000010489dd5f DRW_draw_render_loop_2d_ex + 623
8   org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x00000001056db8d9 image_main_region_draw + 681
9   org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x0000000104cae261 ED_region_do_draw + 337
10  org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x00000001046e3591 wm_draw_update + 1793
11  org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x00000001046df830 WM_main + 48
12  org.blenderfoundation.blender   0x0000000103ecf41e main + 878
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6a968cc9 start + 1
```

Comment: have you searched this topic before posting?   search for "crash file" and see what it says.

Comment: I did, but I couldn't find anything that was related to my situation.

Comment: what does [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/crash.html#crash-log) say?

Comment: I don't have the expertise to understand crash reports.

Comment: Try using the last version of Blender 3.6 : v3.6.9
https://www.blender.org/download/lts/3-6/

Comment: Just tried that. It's still crashing.

Comment: I'd edit my question to copy and past the first 30 lines of the crash report.... down through the stack trace until the first *Thread* line.   I tried to render frame 0 and had no problem, so it might be a resource problem (main memory or GPU mem) or perhaps you need to update your GPU driver.

Comment: Scratching my head searched around a bit on [bug reports](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues).  If no one else gives you help in this forum, consider using Help>>Bug-report.   I see no memory warnings.  Just be sure that your GPU drivers are the latest.

Comment: Ah I see that Ethan did report a bug!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another version of blender or reinstall your blender version.

I open with blender-4.2.0-alpha+main.14b5912eee6f-windows.amd64-release version and this is result:

[image]

Comment: I updated from 3.6.5 to 3.6.9 and still have the same issue. Could it be a computer issue?

Comment: Try to use this version: blender-4.2.0-alpha+main.14b5912eee6f-windows.amd64-release and see the render settings from your computer. You say is a Mac with OS...